# Git subtree split grabs extra folder

Tags: git, git-subtree, subtree

I am getting odd results with git subtree split - I have the following setup:

```
Project/
  file.xml
  WEB-INF/
  build/
  database/
    DATA/
    PUSH/
  lib/
  src/
  test/
```

I'm trying to split off database/.  I used the command:

```
git subtree split -P database/ -b database
```

to create a database branch.  What I get in the database branch is:

```
database/
  DATA/
  PUSH/
  WEB-INF/
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting WEB-INF in here?  If I delete WEB-INF from Project/ before I split but do not commit, it doesn't come along.  So I have a workaround.  But I just don't get it and want to know why Git is not behaving as expected.

FYI, I tried with a branch name that wasn't the same as the directory, got the same problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Just tried to reproduce your problem with no luck. Maybe WEB-INF directory is not in your git repo? Use `git log WEB-INF` to check that - if log is empty, then dir is not in git. Remember, git can't store empty directories, you need to have a file inside.